# worked with datalist asp.net control

Tags: asp.net, datalist, asp.net-controls

I have an HTML code, that want to bind to sql server DB and using the data list asp.net control.as well as we know data list can repeat the code to read all data from DB.
but in my code there is a tag that i don't want to repeat.How can i do this with data list?
this is HTML code before binding:

```
   <div id="welcomeHero">

            <div id="slideshow-main">
                <ul>
                    <li class="p1 active">
                        <a href="www.sdsd.adsf">
                            <img src="images/1_big.gif" width="430" height="290" alt=""/>
                            <span class="opacity"></span>
                            <span class="content">
                            <h1>Title 1</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="p2">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="images/2_big.gif" width="430" height="290" alt=""/>
                            <span class="opacity"></span>
                            <span class="content"><h1>Title 2</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="p3">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="images/3_big.gif" width="430" height="290" alt=""/>
                            <span class="opacity"></span>
                            <span class="content"><h1>Title 3</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>                                       
            </div>

            <div id="slideshow-carousel">               
                  <ul id="carousel" class="jcarousel jcarousel-skin-tango">
                    <li><a href="#" rel="p1"><img src="images/1_big.gif" width="206" height="95" alt="#"/></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" rel="p2"><img src="images/2.gif" width="206" height="95" alt="#"/></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" rel="p3"><img src="images/3.gif" width="206" height="95" alt="#"/></a></li>
                  </ul>
            </div> 
</div>
```

and i don't want to repeat this codes:

```
<div id="welcomeHero">

        <div id="slideshow-main">
            <ul>
</ul>                                       
        </div>

        <div id="slideshow-carousel">    
</div>  
</div>
```

or any idea?

Comment: What do you mean you don't want to repeat? Have you tried [ASP:Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx)?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev: i don't want repeat them because they are main body of that section.look at the HTML code.it's not necessary to repeat all of them and i should repeat <li> tag and inner elements.